# Problem installing x64 guest OS with vmware Server

Tags: 64-bit, vmware

Host OS is x64 Win 2003.

Trying to load x64 iso (Ultrabac) and get the following:
"Attempting to load an x64 operating system, however this CPU is not compatible with x64 mode. Please install a 32-bit X86 operating system. Setup cannot continue. Press any key to exit."

So I ran Processor Check for 64-Bit Compatibility and it came up ok.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need a BIOS that supports virtualisation extensions - checkso
a) that your BIOS has this setting
b) that it is set to ON

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. There's a BIOS setting that had to be enabled for Virtualization.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Do you mean check the BIOS of the VM or the BIOS of the main machine?

Comment: Found it! It's at the main PC's BIOS Setup