# Is there a way to install windows server 2003 x64 over a VM?

Tags: 64-bit, vmware

I have been trying to install that but it produces an error saying that the processor is not compatible with x64. I tried VMWare Player and Microsoft Virtual PC. I also read about disabling virualization but it's not working.

Comment: Your processor it's x32?

Comment: My processor says: Intel Core Duo CPU T9300 @ 2.50 GHz

Comment: System type: 64-Bit Operating system. It's windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling virtualization from the BIOS setup of the main machine it worked!
[Problem installing x64 guest OS with vmware Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744211/problem-installing-x64-guest-os-with-vmware-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, it reveals some very useful informations http://support.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003x64

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't approach Installation on Virtual Machine

Comment: On Virtual PC 2007 documentations it says: Supported Operating Systems:Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition (32-bit x86);Windows Server 2003, Standard x64 Edition;Windows Vista Business;Windows Vista Business 64-bit edition;Windows Vista Enterprise;Windows Vista Enterprise 64-bit edition;Windows Vista Ultimate;Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit edition;Windows XP Professional Edition;Windows XP Professional x64 Edition;Windows XP Tablet PC Edition ;  link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en#AffinityDownloads